# Javascript async and await

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, async-await

I can't understand how async and await works. Consider the code below:

```js
    async function getUsername() {
        await setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("username")
        }, 100)
    }
    
    getUsername();
    console.log("password")
```

I expected the output to be:

```js
   username
   password
```

instead what I get is:

```js
    password
    username
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: _"run this program synchronously"_ - Then don't use `setTimeout` O.o

Comment: `async` and `await` are syntactic sugar to make the work with `Promise`s easier. Your script doesn't use Promises, hence there's no way `async`/`await` would change anything for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can think of `await` as "unraveling" a [`Promise`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise). At the moment your code doesn't use a `Promise` and thus `await` won't work. Instead, you can wrap your `setTimeout` in a promise, and `resolve` your promise once it is complete. Then by using `await` you can get the resolved value from the `Promise` (only once it has been resolved (so after 100m/s)) and log it to the console.

`async` functions will also always return a `Promise`. Thus, you can use the `.then` method on your function call to trigger a "callback" once your `getUsername` function has finished:

```js
async function getUsername() {
    var username = await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(function() {
        resolve("username");
    }, 100));
    
    console.log(username);
}

getUsername().then(res => {
  console.log("password")
}).catch(er => {
  console.error(er);
});
```

While the above code works, I prefer to log my content in the resulting `.then` callback:

```js
const getUsername = async _ => await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(_ => resolve("username"), 100));

getUsername().then(result => {
  console.log(result);
  console.log("password");
}).catch(er => {
  console.error(er);
});
```

Or, if you prefer not to use the `.then` callback and use an `async` function instead you can use:

```js
const getUsername = async _ => await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(_ => resolve("username"), 100));

const getUsernameAndPassword = async _ => {
  const username = await getUsername();
  console.log(username);
  console.log("password");
}

getUsernameAndPassword();
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can't just await setTimeout as it does not return the promise, you could try to turn contents of that function into one if you want to wait for it's execution

```
function getUsername() {
    return new Promise(resolve =>{
        setTimeout(function() {
            console.log("username");
            resolve();
        }, 100)
    })
}
```

On top of that if you have to use `.then` method, so that promise returned from the function will not be ignored and program will wait for the execution anyway

```
getUsername().then(()=>console.log("password"));
```

Answer (score 0):

The async function declaration defines an asynchronous function, which returns an AsyncFunction object.

An asynchronous function is a function which operates asynchronously via the event loop,

using an implicit Promise to return its result. But the syntax and structure of your

code using async functions is much more like using standard synchronous functions.

```
function resolveAfter2Seconds() {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('resolved');
    }, 2000);
  });
}

async function asyncCall() {
  console.log('calling');
  var result = await resolveAfter2Seconds();
  console.log(result);
  // expected output: 'resolved'
}

asyncCall();

async function name([param[, param[, ... param]]]) {
   statements
}
```

**Reference 1** : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

**Reference2** :
 https://medium.com/siliconwat/how-javascript-async-await-works-3cab4b7d21da